# Use Axios(Mock) in test environment

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to integrate axios into my test environment. So far, however, I get the error below when starting the test. I use React testing library with Jest

table.test.js:

```
import { expect, jest, test } from "@jest/globals";
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import axios from "axios";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

jest.mock("axios", () => ({
 __esModule: true,
 default: {
 get: () => ({
   data: { id: 1, name: "Ben" },
  }),
 },
}));
```

> Cannot find module 'axios' from 'src/components/Table/table.test.js'

dependencies

```
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
"@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the axios-mock-adapter NPM package for this instead of making your own axios mock: https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter